# pyFFTW installation into Enthought Canopy

Tags: enthought, fftw, canopy, pyfftw

I am trying to install PyFFTW into Enthought Canopy
I'm on a Mac running Mavericks
The initial command and output are below
the problem seems to be with it finding fftw3.h and gcc failing right after that
can anyone help?
Thanks

Canopy 64bit) iz9mbpro:User iz9$ pip install pyfftw
Downloading/unpacking pyfftw
  Downloading pyFFTW-0.9.2.tar.gz (336kB): 336kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/setup.py) egg_info for package pyfftw

Installing collected packages: pyfftw
  Running setup.py install for pyfftw
    skipping '/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/pyfftw/pyfftw.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'pyfftw.pyfftw' extension
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -I/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/include -I/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/pyfftw -I/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7 -I/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/include -I/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/pyfftw -I/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7 -c /Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/pyfftw/pyfftw.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/pyfftw/pyfftw.o
    In file included from /Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/pyfftw/pyfftw.c:256:
    In file included from /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
    In file included from /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17:
    In file included from /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1760:
    /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by "          "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
    #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
     ^
    /Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/pyfftw/pyfftw.c:260:10: fatal error: 'fftw3.h' file not found
    #include "fftw3.h"
             ^
    1 warning and 1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/sc/wm52xk5528b2m95ztnh15clj5lkhmb/T/pip-29rHyR-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/include/site/python2.7:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/pyfftw

copying pyfftw/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/pyfftw

copying pyfftw/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/pyfftw

copying pyfftw/np_fft.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/pyfftw

creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/pyfftw/builders

copying pyfftw/builders/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/pyfftw/builders

copying pyfftw/builders/_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/pyfftw/builders

copying pyfftw/builders/builders.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/pyfftw/builders

creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/pyfftw/interfaces

copying pyfftw/interfaces/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/pyfftw/interfaces

copying pyfftw/interfaces/_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/pyfftw/interfaces

copying pyfftw/interfaces/cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/pyfftw/interfaces

copying pyfftw/interfaces/numpy_fft.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/pyfftw/interfaces

copying pyfftw/interfaces/scipy_fftpack.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/pyfftw/interfaces

running build_ext

skipping '/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/pyfftw/pyfftw.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)

building 'pyfftw.pyfftw' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/Users

creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/Users/iz9

creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/Users/iz9/Library

creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought

creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit

creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User

creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build

creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw

creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/pyfftw

gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -I/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/include -I/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/pyfftw -I/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7 -I/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/include -I/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/pyfftw -I/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7 -c /Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/pyfftw/pyfftw.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/pyfftw/pyfftw.o

In file included from /Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/pyfftw/pyfftw.c:256:

In file included from /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:

In file included from /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17:

In file included from /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1760:

/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by "          "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]

## warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \

^

/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/pyfftw/pyfftw.c:260:10: fatal error: 'fftw3.h' file not found

## include "fftw3.h"

```
     ^
```

1 warning and 1 error generated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

---

Cleaning up...
Command /Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/sc/wm52xk5528b2m95ztnh15clj5lkhmb/T/pip-29rHyR-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/build/pyfftw
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/iz9/.pip/pip.log

Answer (score 0):

From the [PyPi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyFFTW): "Under linux, to build from source, the FFTW library must be installed already. This should probably work for OSX, though I've not tried it."

There are build instructions for FFTW on Mac at [this page](http://www.fftw.org/install/mac.html).